# Valgrind conditional jump ... error with PCRE2 JIT when reading from file

Tags: c, valgrind, jit, pcre2

I have a very interesting problem.

I'd like to use PCRE2, and its JIT function. The task is simple: read lines from a file, and find patterns.

Here is the sample code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define PCRE2_CODE_UNIT_WIDTH 8
#include <pcre2.h>

int search(pcre2_code *re, unsigned char * subject) {

    pcre2_match_data *match_data_real = pcre2_match_data_create_from_pattern(re, NULL);

    size_t len_subject = strlen((const char *)subject);

    int rc = pcre2_match(
        re,
        (PCRE2_SPTR)subject,
        len_subject,
        0,
        0,
        match_data_real,
        NULL
    );

    pcre2_match_data_free(match_data_real);
    return rc;
}

int main(int argc, char ** argv) {

    unsigned char subject[][100]     = {
        "this is a foobar",
        "this is a barfoo",
        "this is a barbar",
        "this is a foofoo"
    };

    pcre2_code *re;
    PCRE2_SPTR  pattern = (unsigned char *)"foo";
    int         errornumber;
    PCRE2_SIZE  erroroffset;

    re = pcre2_compile(
        pattern,
        PCRE2_ZERO_TERMINATED,
        0,
        &errornumber,
        &erroroffset,
        NULL
    );
    pcre2_jit_compile(re, PCRE2_JIT_COMPLETE);

    FILE *fp;

    int s = 0;
    while(s < 2) {
        search(re, subject[s++]);
    }

    if (argc >= 2) {
        fp = fopen(argv[1], "r");
        if (fp != NULL) {
            char tline[2048];
            while(fgets(tline, 2048, fp) != NULL) {
                search(re, (unsigned char *)tline);
            }
            fclose(fp);
        }
    }

    pcre2_code_free(re);

    return 0;
}
```

Compile the code:

```
gcc -Wall -O2 -g pcretest.c -o pcretest -lpcre2-8
```

As you can see, in line 58 I check if there is an argument given, the code tries to open it as a file.

Also as you can see in line 49, I'd like to use PCRE2's JIT.

The code works as well, but I checked it with Valgrind, and found an interesting behavior:

- if I add a file as argument, then Valgrind reports `Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)` and `Uninitialised value was created by a stack allocation`, but it points to the `main()`. The command:
  `valgrind --tool=memcheck --leak-check=full --show-leak-kinds=all --track-origins=yes -s ./pcretest myfile.txt`
- Without argument, there is no any Valgrind report. Command:
  `valgrind --tool=memcheck --leak-check=full --show-leak-kinds=all --track-origins=yes -s ./pcretest`
- if I comment out the `pcre2_jit_compile((*re), PCRE2_JIT_COMPLETE);` in line 55, then everything works as well, no any Valgrind reports. Command:
  `valgrind --tool=memcheck --leak-check=full --show-leak-kinds=all --track-origins=yes -s ./pcretest myfile.txt`

The Valgrind's relevant output:

```
==31385== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==31385==    at 0x4EECD1A: ???
==31385==    by 0x1FFEFFFC1F: ???
==31385==  Uninitialised value was created by a stack allocation
==31385==    at 0x1090FA: main (pcretest.c:27)
...
==31385== HEAP SUMMARY:
==31385==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==31385==   total heap usage: 12 allocs, 12 frees, 13,486 bytes allocated
==31385== 
==31385== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==31385== 
==31385== ERROR SUMMARY: 1 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
==31385== 
==31385== 1 errors in context 1 of 1:
==31385== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==31385==    at 0x4EECD1A: ???
==31385==    by 0x1FFEFFFC1F: ???
==31385==  Uninitialised value was created by a stack allocation
==31385==    at 0x1090FA: main (pcretest.c:27)
==31385== 
==31385== ERROR SUMMARY: 1 errors from 1 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

In line 27 there is the `int main(...)`.

What do I miss?

Comment: This is where we ask for a [mre].  The code presented is surely not anywhere near the minimum needed to reproduce the issue.  On the other hand, the Valgrind output is only described not presented verbatim.

Comment: Thanks, I replaced the code, hope now it meets the requirements. Also I've added the Valgrind's output.

Comment: That's helpful, thank you.  And I can reproduce your issue.

Comment: Does the Valgrind option `—smc-check=all` help? It may be needed depending on where the jit code is stored.

Comment: @PaulFloyd thanks, unfortunately no, it does not help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Observations**:

- The Valgrind report is telling you that the uninitialized data being accessed are in the stack frame of the initial call to `main()`.  However,
- even though you're compiling with debug information, the Valgrind report does not implicate a specific variable.  Also,
- the report's stack trace for the error does not present function names, and does not trace back to `main()`.  And of course,
- the error is not reported when you disable JIT compilation of the pattern.

Apparently, then, **the error is associated with the machine code generated by PCRE2's JIT compiler**.  If you don't perform JIT compilation then you get correct operation via the ordinary matching path.  If you *do* perform JIT compilation then the JIT-generated code is engaged, and that code triggers the Valgrind error.  You might nevertheless get correct matching, but I would not rely on that for code that triggers the Valgrind error observed.

I played around with variations on your code, and discovered that the error is specifically associated with the calls to `pcre2_match_data_create_from_pattern()` and `pcre2_match()` in function `search()`.  Either one will cause Valgrind to report the error.  But **why does the error occur only in some calls to `search()`**?

It seems likely to be because the JIT compilation sets up data structures in `main()`'s stack frame that are clobbered by executing the body of the `if (argc > 2)` statement.  This is consistent with the fact that I was able to avoid the error by adding an initializer for variable `tline` in that block:

```
            char tline[2048] = {0};
```

I can imagine a variety of scenarios for why that might make a difference, all having to do with how the JIT-generated code and the compiler-generated code manipulate the stack pointer.

Personally, discovering such an issue would likely persuade me to stay far away from PCRE's JIT compiler.  Definitely I would do that at least until I had evidence of pattern matching being a performance hotspot for my program.  If you must engage the JIT, however, then here are some recommendations that might (or might not) help you avoid trouble:

1. Take "just in time" to heart: perform JIT as close as possible to when you actually use the pattern.
2. Do not assume that the JIT code is long-term viable.  In particular, it probably is unsafe to use after the function that calls the JIT compiler returns, but it might not be good even that long.
3. Use the JIT-compiled regex (only) in the same function that runs the JIT compiler.
4. Make that function as simple as possible.
5. Declare all local variables of that function at the beginning, with initializers.
6. Test thoroughly.

That's more than seems to have been necessary to resolve the issue for your particular example code, but it's aimed more generally at reducing the cross section for the compiled program violating assumptions made by the JIT.

Comment: First, thanks for your time, I very appreciate it. "It seems likely to be because the JIT compilation sets up data structures in main()'s stack frame" - in my first code this was in a separated function (but that was also called from main()). "I was able to avoid the error by adding an initializer for variable tline in that block:" - I can confirm that this works for me too. I didn't think that this is needed, because later fgets() sets it. But... that's it. **

Comment: ** ""Personally, discovering such an issue would likely persuade me to stay far away from PCRE's JIT compiler." - sure, but with JIT is faster, and the speed is important in my case. Thanks for tips, I'll review all of them. Finally, meanwhile I asked this question on pcre2-dev list too, and the author of PCRE2 reports that sometime the test cases also give false positive results like this one. Here is the thread: https://groups.google.com/g/pcre2-dev/c/5ezMLhcEu14.

Comment: One more note: author of PCRE2 wrote that this error comes on machine which supports SSE2 - but I think most (not so modern HW) supports it. Mine does, at least...

Comment: @airween, I am not surprised that the PCRE folks have seen this before.  I can believe that it is related to code generation that makes use of SSE instructions.  I am not particularly surprised that they use a Valgrind suppression file to prevent Valgrind from reporting on it.  I am skeptical of their claim that the issue constitutes a false positive, but I am not interested in pursuing the matter further at this time.

Answer (score 0):

This is indeed caused by efficient use of SSE2. CPU-s use 1K or bigger pages to map memory, so a 16 byte aligned 16 byte read (SSE2 registers are 16 byte long) which intersects with a valid buffer is always valid. However, bytes before the start or after the end of the buffer might never be initialized. The algorithm ignores these bytes, so the random data (regardless it is initialized or not) have no effect on any computation.

Comment: Thanks. Meanwhile I made some researches, and found this explanation, but thank you for this.